# dataframe in python with related points

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe with n different values (in this case it would be points), my idea is for example: I have 4 points, p1, p2, p3, p4. i want to get a dataframe in python with these related points (without repeating the same relation). Example

list=[p1,p2,p3,p4]

i want :

column1 | column2

p1 | p2

p1 | p3

p1 | p4

p2 | p3

p2 | p4

p3 | p4

the same if i have n points : ejample

list=[p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]

column1 | column2

p1 | p2

p1 | p3

p1 | p4

p1 | p5

p2 | p3

p2 | p4

p2 | p5

p3 | p4

p3 | p5

p4 | p5

i have not idea how to do it .... i can deduce that this is equal to Σ, i = 1 -> n, (n-1) but I don't know how to get it to dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools` to the rescue.

```
import itertools
results = itertools.combinations( [p1,p2,p3,p4], 2 )
df = pandas.DataFrame( results, columns=["column 1","column2 "])
```

Comment: hahahhaha amazing , give me 7 min and i click your answerd as correct :D

Answer (score 0):

I think a more practical representation for your problem is labeling columns and rows with the point names , and then marking where they over lap accordingly with a zero or a 1. i.e. if you were using pandas in python

```
  datapoints = [p1,p2...]  
  dfObj = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = datapoints , index=datapoints)
  dfObj[0,1] = 0 #to mark no relation 
  dfObj[0,0] = 1 #to mark a relation
```